# Problems when communicating with SD card using ethernet shield

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, sd-card

I am using the "SD read/write" code from the Arduino IDE examples to test an ethernet shield (clone). The problem is that although a file is created no data is stored in it.

When running the serial monitor will only show the first characters of the *Serial.print()* sentences, e.g when doing *Serial.print("Initializing SD card...")* the serial monitors displays *Ini* or *In* and nothing else.
Also the IDE shows the following error message: (some words in spanish)

```
Error dentro de Serial.serialEvent()
java.io.IOException: Error de entrada/salida in nativeavailable
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.nativeavailable(Native Method)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.available(RXTXPort.java:1598)
at processing.app.Serial.serialEvent(Serial.java:258)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.sendEvent(RXTXPort.java:774)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.eventLoop(Native Method)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$MonitorThread.run(RXTXPort.java:1644)
```

I have tried with 2 different SD cards, including a brand new one, and 2 different Arduino Uno (a clone and an original one). The OS is Ubuntu 13.10.

My guess is that it has something to do with the *myFile.println()* sentences, when they are commented the serial monitor works fine.

Any help is much appreciated since I couldn't find the problem anywhere else so far!